# in which condition will queue_work() not wake up the work queue in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

i am learning linux kernel, and i meet a problem.
in linux kernel, i use "mod_delayed_work(bdi_wq, &wb->dwork, 0)" to queue a work_struct to a work queue, i assume the work function of the queued work_struct will soon be executed. but work function is not executed until 300 seconds later.
and i find a watchdog thread happens meanwhile.
does this a normal case? or is it because of the watchdog thread that make the work queue sleep although there is a work(my queued work_truct) pending here.

added:
the followings are my condition. i use the linux kernel 4.9.13 codes and do not change them except for adding some printk logs.
i have five disks, and use five shells to copy 4GB files from disks to disks concurrently. this problem happens while i am doing sync. one of the shells is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<9999; i++))
    do
    cp disk1/4GB.tar disk2/4GB-chen.tar
    sync
    rm disk2/4GB-chen.tar
    sync
done
```

i do a sync after each copy is done. after the shells run for some times, i find that the sync command will be blocked for a long time(longer than 2 minutes). i find sync will call a system call, the code is as follows:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(sync)
{
    int nowait = 0, wait = 1;
    wakeup_flusher_threads(0, WB_REASON_SYNC);
    iterate_supers(sync_inodes_one_sb, NULL);
    iterate_supers(sync_fs_one_sb, &nowait);
    iterate_supers(sync_fs_one_sb, &wait);
    iterate_bdevs(fdatawrite_one_bdev, NULL);
    iterate_bdevs(fdatawait_one_bdev, NULL);
    if (unlikely(laptop_mode))
        laptop_sync_completion();
    return 0;
}
```

in iterate_supers(sync_inodes_one_sb, NULL), kernel will call sync_inodes_one_sb for each disk'super block. sync_inodes_one_sb will eventually call sync_inodes_sb, the code is:

```
void sync_inodes_sb(struct super_block *sb)
{
    DEFINE_WB_COMPLETION_ONSTACK(done);
    struct wb_writeback_work work = {
        .sb     = sb,
        .sync_mode  = WB_SYNC_ALL,
        .nr_pages   = LONG_MAX,
        .range_cyclic   = 0,
        .done       = &done,
        .reason     = WB_REASON_SYNC,
        .for_sync   = 1,
    };
    struct backing_dev_info *bdi = sb->s_bdi;
    /*
     * Can't skip on !bdi_has_dirty() because we should wait for !dirty
     * inodes under writeback and I_DIRTY_TIME inodes ignored by
     * bdi_has_dirty() need to be written out too.
     */
    if (bdi == &noop_backing_dev_info)
        return;
    WARN_ON(!rwsem_is_locked(&sb->s_umount));
    bdi_split_work_to_wbs(bdi, &work, false);  /* split work to wbs */
    wb_wait_for_completion(bdi); 
    wait_sb_inodes(sb);
}
```

and in bdi_split_work_to_wbs(bdi, &work, false)(in fs/fs-writeback.c), queue the write back works to the work queue:

```
static void bdi_split_work_to_wbs(struct backing_dev_info *bdi,
                  struct wb_writeback_work *base_work,
                  bool skip_if_busy)
{
    struct bdi_writeback *last_wb = NULL;
    struct bdi_writeback *wb = list_entry(&bdi->wb_list,
                          struct bdi_writeback, bdi_node);
    might_sleep();
restart:
    rcu_read_lock();
    list_for_each_entry_continue_rcu(wb, &bdi->wb_list, bdi_node) {
        DEFINE_WB_COMPLETION_ONSTACK(fallback_work_done);
        struct wb_writeback_work fallback_work;
        struct wb_writeback_work *work;
        long nr_pages;
        if (last_wb) {
            wb_put(last_wb);
            last_wb = NULL;
        }
        /* SYNC_ALL writes out I_DIRTY_TIME too */
        if (!wb_has_dirty_io(wb) &&
            (base_work->sync_mode == WB_SYNC_NONE ||
             list_empty(&wb->b_dirty_time)))
            continue;
        if (skip_if_busy && writeback_in_progress(wb))
            continue;
        nr_pages = wb_split_bdi_pages(wb, base_work->nr_pages);
        work = kmalloc(sizeof(*work), GFP_ATOMIC);
        if (work) {
            *work = *base_work;
            work->nr_pages = nr_pages;
            work->auto_free = 1;
            wb_queue_work(wb, work);      /*** here to queue write back work ***/
            continue;
        }
        /* alloc failed, execute synchronously using on-stack fallback */
        work = &fallback_work;
        *work = *base_work;
        work->nr_pages = nr_pages;
        work->auto_free = 0;
        work->done = &fallback_work_done;
        wb_queue_work(wb, work);
        /*
         * Pin @wb so that it stays on @bdi->wb_list.  This allows
         * continuing iteration from @wb after dropping and
         * regrabbing rcu read lock.
         */
        wb_get(wb);
        last_wb = wb;
        rcu_read_unlock();
        wb_wait_for_completion(bdi, &fallback_work_done);
        goto restart;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    if (last_wb)
        wb_put(last_wb);
}
```

use wb_queue_work(wb, work) to queue a work to work structure, in fs/fs-writeback.c wb_queue_work is:

```
static void wb_queue_work(struct bdi_writeback *wb,
              struct wb_writeback_work *work)
{
    trace_writeback_queue(wb, work);
    if (work->done)
        atomic_inc(&work->done->cnt);
    spin_lock_bh(&wb->work_lock);
    if (test_bit(WB_registered, &wb->state)) {
        list_add_tail(&work->list, &wb->work_list);
        mod_delayed_work(bdi_wq, &wb->dwork, 0);     /*** queue work to work queue ***/
    } else
        finish_writeback_work(wb, work);
    spin_unlock_bh(&wb->work_lock);
}
```

here the mod_delayed_work(bdi_wq, &wb->dwork, 0) will actually queue the wb->dwork to the bdi_wq work queue, the work function of wb->dwork is wb_workfn()(in fs/fs-writeback.c), i add some printks when prepare to queue the work and in the work function, i find the printk logs in the work function are not printed out until approximately 300 seconds later some times(most of the times, they will be printed less than 1 seconds after the work has been queued to the work queue). and the bdi_wq work queue will be blocked until 300 seconds later when the work function begin to be executed.

Comment: `does this a normal case?` - No, this is not normal. Show the code (in form of [mcve]). BTW, this is a rule of Stack Overflow to show the code which corresponds to the problem.

Comment: i have depicted my steps and the codes when encountering this problem, i just use linux 4.9.13 kernel source code and do not change them.

Comment: Well, so this is a stress test. Are you sure that there is no other works in the `bdi_wq` workqueue? This workqueue is used not only in `wb_queue_work` function.

Comment: eh...i'm not sure about whether there are works pending in bdi_wq, i will check it out(but i do not know how to find whether there are other works in the bdi_wq or not...can you give me some advice?). and if there are other works pending in the bdi_wq when i am queuing work, should it take that long time to complete the pending works? in other normal case, i find it takes just a few seconds or at worst dozens of seconds from queuing works to executing works. i have met the case for some times that it takes about 300 seconds from queuing to executing the work, does 300 seconds a special value?

Comment: i find that, it is because that there are a lot of works pending in bdi_wq workqueue before i queue my work, so it will take a long time until executing my work. and 300 seconds is not a special value, just by accident it will take about 300 seconds to finish the pending works. thanks a lot for helping me.